# После закрытия окна остается висеть процесс.

Tags: c++, opengl, mingw, glut

Здравствуйте. Копаю Glut и OpenGL. Компилирую MinGW:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -mwindows glut32.lib -lopengl32 -lglu32
```

Код программы (использовал не только этот - все такая же проблема):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

void display()
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glBegin(GL_LINES);
  glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  glVertex2f(0.25, 0.25);
  glVertex2f(0.75, 0.75);
  glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  glVertex2f(0.75, 0.25);
  glVertex2f(0.25, 0.75);
  glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  glVertex2f(0.50, 0.25);
  glVertex2f(0.50, 0.75);
  glEnd();
  glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
  glutInitWindowSize(240, 240);
  glutInitWindowPosition(100, 740);
  glutCreateWindow("Test");
  glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;
}
```

Суть такова - программа работает хорошо , всё компилируется  , предупреждений нет. Но закрыв окно программы (любым способом) процесс остается висеть в диспетчере. Поэтому приходится заходить каждый раз в процессы и там вырубать main.exe. Как это побороть?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: [учитесь искать][1]

[1]:http://www.gamedev.ru/code/forum/?id=81178

Comment: @Gordio, расшифруйте, пожалуйста, что Вы имели в виду

Answer (score 1):

> Поэтому приходится заходить каждый раз в процессы и там вырубать main.exe

Если подождать некоторое время, то процесс сам не заканчивается?

А вообще ответ таков, что процесс и не должен оставаться в памяти.

[**3.090 How can I make glutMainLoop() return to my calling program?**](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/glut.htm)

> glutMainLoop() isn't designed to return to the calling routine. GLUT was designed around the idea of an event-driven application, with the exit method being captured through an input event callback routine, such as a GLUT menu or keyboard callback handler.
> If you insist on returning to your program from glutMainLoop(), there is only one way to do so. You need to download the GLUT source and hack gluMainLoop() to do what you want it to. Then compile and link into your program this hacked version of glutMainLoop().

Comment: Проследил - 20 минут прошло , процесс висит...My English is bad...

Comment: Написано, что

1. glutMainLoop() не возвращает управление обратно в программу.
2. GLUT сам обрабатывает ситуацию завершения программы.

Comment: @Overдоз, видимо Вам нужно зарегистрировать обработчик какого-то события, который будет делать exit(0);